# How can I use SVG in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-icons

I am trying to use bootstrap icons in react native and I can't find any useful methods on how to render an SVG in react-native. Does anyone know how to?

Comment: I am curious, may I do a short interview? Have you used the search box at the top of this page? How many StackOverflow posts did you read? How can we make StackOverflow better answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Add SVGs in react native you can use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg)

**Install:**

> yarn add react-native-svg

**Example:**

```
import Svg, {
  Circle,
  Ellipse,
  G,
  Text,
  TSpan,
  TextPath,
  Path,
  Polygon,
  Polyline,
  Line,
  Rect,
  Use,
  Image,
  Symbol,
  Defs,
  LinearGradient,
  RadialGradient,
  Stop,
  ClipPath,
  Pattern,
  Mask,
} from 'react-native-svg';

/* Use this if you are using Expo
import * as Svg from 'react-native-svg';
const { Circle, Rect } = Svg;
*/

import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class SvgExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
          { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
        ]}
      >
        <Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <Circle
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="45"
            stroke="blue"
            strokeWidth="2.5"
            fill="green"
          />
          <Rect
            x="15"
            y="15"
            width="70"
            height="70"
            stroke="red"
            strokeWidth="2"
            fill="yellow"
          />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Or you want to import an svg to your app use: [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer)

**Example:**

```
import Logo from "./logo.svg";

<Logo width={120} height={40} />
```

But if you want an icon library you can use : [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Also here is the directory: [React Native Vector Icons directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

Answer (score 0):

Recommond [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/languages/svg/#svg-in-javascript)

```
const logo = new URL('logo.svg', import.meta.url);
export function Logo() {return <img src={logo} alt="logo" />}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score -1):

I just found out an easy way to solve this problem that works for me.

I'm using Expo and I have `react-native-svg` installed. Note that this is different from importing `SvgUri` from `react-native-svg-uri`. That is a different library.

```
import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";
```

```
<SvgUri
  uri="https://example.com/uploads/apple.svg"
  width="40%"
  height="40%"
/>
```